# How to rename a publishing page in code

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I'm trying to do a bulk page rename (NB. the file name e.g. default.aspx, not the displayed title)

```
foreach (PublishingPage page in pweb.GetPublishingPages())
{
    Console.WriteLine(page.Name);
    page.Name = GetNewNamingConventionForPage(page.Name); //error, it's read only
}
```

What gives? I can rename it manually in the pages library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `"FileLeafRef"` field of the underlying `SPListItem` for the publishing page.  You need to first check out the file (or create it and then Update it for new sites), update the `.ListItem["FileLeafRef"]` property and then check it back in and publish it.

This code is to create a new publishing page and then change the file name.  You have to run the `.Update` on the PublishingPage before setting the FileLeafRef otherwise you get an `"object does not exist"` error.

```
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(curWeb))
{
    PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(curWeb);
    PublishingPage pubPage = pubWeb.AddPublishingPage();

    pubPage.Title = "My New Page Title";
    pubPage.Update();

    pubPage.ListItem["FileLeafRef"] = "default";  //.aspx is added automatically
    pubPage.ListItem.SystemUpdate();  //SystemUpdate doesn't update the modified fields
    pubPage.CheckIn("");
    pubPage.ListItem.File.Publish("");
}
```

**Update**: BaseName changed to FileLeafRef, BaseName is readonly and we can't update this field.

Comment: i've renamed them all by hand now, but i'll trust you that this works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its beacuse PublishingPage.Name is a read-only property.

You could try:

```
page.ListItem("Name")
```

I have not tested this so do not know if this will do exactly what you need, but you definitely cannot set using the Name property.

Comment: this sounds right.. also note the difference between the name (filename) and the title..

Comment: doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = oldUrl.Replace(oldFileName, newFileName);
publPage.ListItem.File.MoveTo(url);
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a little more explanation to your answer than just the code, otherwise it gets automatically flagged. Thanks.